# Add Arrow Head to CubicCurve, JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to add an arrow head to a cubic curve? I can think of a very tedious way to do it (adding a shape, and control its direction, etc). But I am hoping there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another simpler workaround (2 steps):

1. Add a polygon shape (triangle) in the node which is supposed to
   receive a curve. Have this triangle place in the location where the
   curve's end point will be set.
2. Then, set this triangle to visible when a curve is drawn and to not
   visible when the curve is deleted.

It is not perfect, but look good and does the job!

Answer (score 2):

I seriously doubt that this is a built-in functionality in javafx, and your best bet would be to make a simple polygon arrow head and size it to the size you want, and then 'anchor' the middle of one of the sides to the end of the spline. If you make an equilateral triangle you'll save yourself some sadness. Also, to make sure the direction is correct all you'd have to do is to make sure that the part of the line connecting to your triangle is perpendicular to the base of the triangle, then it'll always be pointing in the 'correct' direction.

An example of the polygon creation for a triangle would be:

```
Polygon polygon1 = new Polygon(new double[]{

            45 , 10 ,

            10 , 80 ,

            80 , 80 ,

        });
```

That makes a a basic red one. :) good luck!

Comment: I could not find an arrow head (or anything remotely related) in the docs. I guess will have to hard code it. Would be really great if this was added. It is a very useful for any data visualization context. Thanks :)